# Can't save changes to database. Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm working on a project for a client. And I seem to be having some trouble being able to edit records through the form.

I basically have a 1-Many relationship between Constituent and ConstituentAddress and a 1-many relationship between Address and ConstituentAddress. The ConstituentAddress(assignment table) has additional data regarding the address such as whether it is the preferred address, the billing address and the type(Home, Work, etc).

Basically, there is a Constituent, an Address and a ConstituentAddress Tables. The relationship is a many-to-many with payload.

Now, I'm able to edit the Constituents perfectly fine when I select just the constituent, but when I go to edit the address using the code posted below, i get the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfP1K.jpg ﻿﻿

"Store update, insert or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows(0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."

The database is housed in Windows Azure, and I can go there to manually edit rows.

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if more information is needed. Thank you.

```
//My edit address action
public ActionResult EditAddress(int? id)
{
     var view = from ca in db.ConstituentAddresses
                 where ca.Id == id
                 select new EditAddressVM
                 {
                      zAddress = ca.Address,
                      zConstituent = ca.Constituent,
                      zConstituentAddress = ca
                 };
     var eavm = new EditAddressVM();
     eavm = view.First();
     if (eavm.zAddress == null || eavm.zConstituent == null)
     {
      return HttpNotFound();
     }
     return View("EditAddress", eavm);
}
```

The variables preceded by a 'z' are part of the View Model and is essentially just used to easily differentiate from what is the view model and what is the dbcontext.

```
//My edit address post action
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditAddress(EditAddressVM eavm)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          var address = eavm.zAddress;
          var constituent = eavm.zConstituent;
          var constAddr = eavm.zConstituentAddress;

          db.Entry(constituent).State = EntityState.Modified;
          db.Entry(address).State = EntityState.Modified;
          db.Entry(constAddr).State = EntityState.Modified;
          db.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = constituent.ConstituentId });
     }
     return View("Index");
}
```

This the Edit Address view(EditAddress.cshtml). I have another view, Edit.cshtml, that only edits the Constituent and that view works perfectly fine. I'll probably want to remove the Constituent data from this form in the future, so that I am just editing the Address and ConstituentAddress.

```
//My Edit address view
@model ContactManager.MVC.Models.EditAddressVM

@{  ViewBag.Title = "EditAddress"; }

<h2>Edit Address</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Constituent Address</legend>

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.ConstituentId)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.zConstituent.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.zConstituent.LastName)

    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.zConstituent.FirstName)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.zConstituent.FirstName)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.zConstituent.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.zConstituent.LastName)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.zConstituent.LastName)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.zConstituent.LastName)
    </div>

    @* Address Data *@
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.AddressId)
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.zAddress.Street)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.zAddress.Street)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.zAddress.Street)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.zAddress.City)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.zAddress.City)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.zAddress.City)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.zAddress.State)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.zAddress.State)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.zAddress.State)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.zAddress.ZipCode)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.zAddress.ZipCode)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.zAddress.ZipCode)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.zAddress.Country)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.zAddress.Country)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.zAddress.Country)
    </div>

    @* Constituent Address Data *@
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.Id)
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.AddressType)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.AddressType)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.AddressType)
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.Id)
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.isBilling)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.isBilling)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.isBilling)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.isPreferred)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.isPreferred)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.isPreferred)
    </div>

    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
}

<div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first mistake is you are not sending all primary key ids via hidden fields, if they are posted null, you will get this error, here you are passing **ConstitutionAddressId** instead of **COnstitutionId**

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.ConstituentId)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.zConstituent.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.zConstituent.LastName)

    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.zConstituent.FirstName)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.zConstituent.FirstName)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.zConstituent.FirstName)
    </div>
```

here you should be  passing : `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zConstituent.Id)`like something.

Long story short, if you create a new object and tell **EF** that its modified using the `EntityState.Modified` then it will throw this error as it doesn't yet exist in the database.

The issue is caused by either one of two things :-

First=> You tried to update a row with one or more properties are Concurrency Mode: Fixed .. and the Optimistic Concurrency prevented the data from being saved. Ie. some changed the row data between the time you received the server data and when you saved your server data.

Second=> You tried to update or delete a row but the row doesn't exist. Another example of someone changing the data (in this case, removing) in between a retrieve then save OR you're flat our trying to update a field which is not an Identity (ie. StoreGeneratedPattern = Computed) and that row doesn't exist.

Comment: So I went back and made that change. '@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zConstituent.ConstituentId'

Comment: (continued)
Unfortunately, now I get a different error:
THe UPDATE statement conflicted with FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.ConstituentAddresses_dbo.Addresses_AddressId". The conflict in Database "TestDB", table "dbo.Addresses", column 'AddressId'. The statement has been terminated.

Here is an image of the [error](http://imgur.com/Cx1qubz)

Comment: now you have foreign key reference error, the foreign key which is passed in table does not exists in the parent table or its going 0 which is not in parent table

Comment: Ok, so after rereading your initial post, I've realized you were right and I see what I did wrong. I needed a HiddenFor statement for each Primary Key and Foreign Key involved in the edit action.

`@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.ConstituentId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zConstituentAddress.AddressId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zConstituent.ConstituentId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zAddress.AddressId)`

This fixes both errors and allows me to save.

Comment: Yes and i told you that in my post